# can I make squid working over socks proxy

Tags: proxy, squid

> client <== http proxy ==> squid server <===== via socks5 proxy===>
>   internet

Is there any possibility to make squid server access internet through socks5 proxy?

Answer (score 3):

In short, yes: Look up 4.10 of the squid [FAQ's](http://docstore.mik.ua/squid/FAQ-4.html#ss4.10)

[Here's some more info](http://www.nikoz.org/nikozweb/docs/linux/how-to/squid/) (near the top, 4.9)

I've never tried this so i cant give you detailed instructions first-hand, unfortunately.